# knockout format data without binding handlers

Tags: javascript, jquery, data-binding, knockout.js

I have a knockout viewmodel which has currency and percentages within it stored as numbers (as opposed to text). I would like to display these numbers in a nice textual format in various places. Namely some of them go within standalone span elements, like so:

```
<span data-bind="formatCurrency: totalOutstandingBalance"></span>
```

others go into a table, and use recursion to display them. I can use a binding handler to format these values, specifically for knockout, like so (this works):

```
ko.bindingHandlers.formatCurrency = {
        init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
            ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, {text: valueAccessor, '$#,##0.#0')});
        }
    };
```

However, at some point within my code (an in-house graphing library) I need to use similar formatting code, like so (this works with the inhouse library):

```
function formatCurrency(value) {
    return lib.formatter.formatNumber(value, '$#,##0.#0');
}

console.log(formatCurrency(512.17));
```

I have to format various things, percentages, currency, integers, doubles, dates and so on. And I have now accumulated bindingHandlers and generic functions for each of those instances. My question is whether I can somehow use this generic formatCurrency code and so on, for both my non-knockout formatting needs and for my knockout formatting, thereby eliminating the need to have double functions in my code that format my text text.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you call the `formatCurrency` method from your bindingHandler?

```
function formatCurrency(value) {
    return lib.formatter.formatNumber(value, '$#,##0.#0');
}

ko.bindingHandlers.formatCurrencyHandler = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        $(element).html(formatCurrency(valueAccessor);
    }
};
```

If you are sure that you will get a Number, you can even add `formatCurrency` to Number prototype:

```
Number.prototype.formatCurrency = function () { return lib.formatter.formatNumber(this, '$#,##0.#0'); }

$(element).html(valueAccessor.formatCurrency());
```

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using computed observables. For example, in your viewmodel, you could have a computed observable named `formattedPrice` (just an example):

```
self.formattedPrice = ko.computed(function () {
      return lib.formatter.formatNumber(self.actualPrice(), '$#,##0.#0');
});
```

`actualPrice` would be the observable you have in your viewmodel having the price in number.

More on computed observables : http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html

Comment: That still duplicates my work. I will have observables, computed observables (which do formatting) and I will still have the generic javascript methods that do non-KO based formatting.

Comment: IMO, you would need to have a KO-based and a non-KO based formatting functions. I don't think there is an escape from that. I could be wrong, though.